# for-loop without stop condition?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, for-loop

I just finished the FreecodeCamp.com quiz [Intermediate Algorithm Scripting: Smallest Common Multiple](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple).

The code is working fine for the test cases they give (`[1, 5]`, `[5, 1]` `[23, 18]` and `[1, 13]`) but if I use a bigger range I also have to edit the code and increase the stop condition for the `for`-loop, and when I remove the stop condition from the loop, it gives an error.

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const creatArray = (start, stop, step) =>
    Array.from(
      { length: (stop - start) / step + 1 },
      (_, i) => start + i * step
    );
  let myArray = creatArray(arr[0], arr[arr.length - 1], 1);
  for (let i = myArray[myArray.length - 1]; i < 10000000; i++) {
    if (myArray.every((e) => calback(e, i))) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

let calback = (elem, e) => e % elem === 0;

console.log(smallestCommons([1, 5]));
```

Is there any simple fix to this code? Is my solution efficient or is there are better way to tackle the problem?

Thanks

Comment: link to the quiz https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple

Comment: Can you provide an example for a call to `smallestCommons` that shows the error?

Comment: console.log(smallestCommons([90,18])); i will i have to incrase the stop conditon by allot to fin the smaletCommons of all nimber between 18 - 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to explain a little of the code; what we do first is to sort the array since it is an array of two numbers, after we sort it, we need to create a new array to store the path from the first element to the second one; we define the diference between the greatest and the smallest number in order to create a for to store the path, after we store the path; we define two functions for finding the grand common divisor and the Least Common Multiple; after that we use a reduce to get the Value of the LCM. Hope this helps you, the algorithm of the gcd is based on [Euclidean Division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm)

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  arr = arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b)
  let newarr = []
  let dif = arr[1]-arr[0]
  for(let i=0; i<= dif;i++){
        newarr.push(arr[0]+i)
  }
  const gcd = (a,b)=>a?gcd(b%a,a):b;
  const lcm = (a,b)=> a/gcd(a,b)*b
  return newarr.reduce(lcm);
}

console.log(smallestCommons([1, 5]));
console.log(smallestCommons([90,10]));
```